# it is possible sign helm charts with cloud KMS key?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, google-cloud-kms

is it possible to sign a Helm chart with a Google Cloud Platform Cloud KMS (Key Management Service) key? Currently I use a gpg key but, I don't want another team member have the key locally in order to sign other packages with the same key.

I want to use same key i use with cosign to sign other artifacts, like:

`cosign sign --key gcpkms://projects/<my-key>/vers/1 <image> --fulcio-url=<fulcio.com> --rekor-url=<rekor.com> --yes`

I tried signing with helm but it just didn't work because wait for --keyring comand.

`helm package --sign --key gcpkms://projects/<my-key>/vers/1 /path/to/chart`

The output message I get is `Error: private key not found`